# How can I rotate my laptops built in display?

Tags: display, screen, xrandr, rotate

I have a Lenovo Yoga with Ubuntu 17.10. If I attach an external monitor I can flip that but not the built in display in the system display settings as shown on images below. Can someone suggest some hack to make such option for the built in display too?

Built in display has no 'Orientation' option:
[image: Built in display has no 'Orientation' option]

External display has 'Orientation' option:
[image: External display has 'Orientation' option]

`xrandr -q` output is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1100, maximum 8192 x 8192

XWAYLAND1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+

XWAYLAND2 connected 1920x1080+0+20 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
```

I tried `xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --rotate inverted` but it does not work, gives error

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

I used all possible XWAYLAND[n] numbers. None is working. After plugging in and out the screen or reconfiguring to one and back again to two monitor setup, some renumbering happens. Tried with those new numbers, none worked.

`xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --rotate inverted`
and

`xrandr --output XWAYLAND2 --rotate inverted`

run without error but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two outputs: `XWAYLAND1` and `XWAYLAND2`.

Because your external monitor is 23 inches or 584.2 milimeters (`XWAYLAND1`), I assume your built-in-display is `XWAYLAND2`.

Use this command instead:

```
xrandr --output XWAYLAND2 --rotate inverted
```

Comment: I used all possible numbers. None is working. Sorry I missed that from the question. I edit the original question now.